# ReSize SizeChanged event not fired when clicking on an application running in the taskbar

Tags: c#, winforms, minimize

I want to do something when the using clicks on an application running in the task bar. So I found out that I have to handle the ReSize and SizeChanged events.

I implemented event handlers for both and it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't.

By that I mean that sometimes when I click on the icon in the taskbar it would fire the event but sometimes it doesn't.

Has anyone experienced the same?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Form.Activated event to catch when the icon is clicked.